# Add selection of flag icons using ngx-translate ( Angular 16 )

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I want to I have added ngx-translat to my project, but I want to add a selection from flags.

For now, I have flags near each other, if I am using  ... it doesn't work.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';


Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {


  constructor(private translateServeice: TranslateService) {
      translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
      translateService.use('en');
  }
}

  changeLanguage(language: string): void {
    this.translateService.use(language);
  }
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
          <div class="flag" (click)="changeLanguage('nl')"><img src="/assets/images/nl.svg"></div>
          <div class="flag" (click)="changeLanguage('en')"><img src="/assets/images/us.svg"></div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to use the Angular i18n instead of `ngx-translate`.
You can check more information on why here: [Discussion: future of the library](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/783)